# Rewriting Certain Variables in Other Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, basically I am writing a batch file where there are multiple variables that are called from another batch file called profiledata.bat.

The program checks to see if the file exists. If not, it should create a new file.

```
if exist \user\profiledata.bat (
    set Pdata_exist=true
    goto askPdata
) else (
    goto newPdata
)

:newPdata
if exist \user\NUL (
    if Pdata_exist=true goto delPdata
    cd \user
    goto addPdata
) else (
    mkdir \user
    cd \user
    goto addPdata
)
set var2=10
echo set var1=%var2%>profiledata.bat
set var2=20
echo set var1=%var2%>profiledata.bat
REM Var1 is rewritten because var 2 changed.
```

It will then write your computer info to the file. However, I want it so that if a certain thing changes later on, it will just rewrite that variable and not the rest of the file.

For example the `echo` command along with the `>` will rewrite the whole script not just `variable`. I can't have that. Instead I want to rewrite just `variable`.

Comment: I don't see a single `ECHO` command in your code so I don't know what you need help with.  Also, when using the `IF` command for string comparisons you need to use two equals symbols: `==`

Comment: @Squashman Yes sorry, I was quickly writing the code and I did not realize my mistake. Thank you. The echo commands were removed because I figured out I was not able use them without overriding the data in the batch file. I will quickly add them.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want profiledata.bat to look like. I am not understanding the description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed all of your leading back slashes and isolated your Pdata_exist variables by enclosing them in double quotes.

```bat
if exist user\profiledata.bat (
    set "Pdata_exist=true"
    goto askPdata
) else (
    goto newPdata
)

:newPdata
if exist user\ (
    if "%Pdata_exist%"=="true" goto delPdata
    cd user
    goto addPdata
) else (
    mkdir user
    cd user
    goto addPdata
)
```